# Block IPv6 Traffic using iptables on Linux using Layer 2 info [bad substitution/argument]

Tags: networking, iptables

i'm trying to block IPv6 traffic on my router's end following the tutorial [here](https://superuser.com/questions/488341/block-ipv6-traffic-using-iptables-on-linux-using-layer-2-info) by Claudius's suggestion, with the following command:

```
ip6tables -I FORWARD -d ${IP(Node1)} -j REJECT
```

But i'm getting the output error:

```
bash: ${IP(Node1)}: bad substitution
```

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: You have to supply that information.  `-d` is used for the Destination of where the packet is going to.  So, that would be the fixed IP of a system that it is being forwarded to.  So you would replace the `${IP(Node1)}` with the IP of the Node.  The first line of `ip6tables -I FORWARD -o eth0 -j REJECT` should be enough and make sure to change `eth0` to match the port or interface name of the network device.  When in doubt, check the man pages.  `man ip6tables`

Comment: Much obliged. Thank you for the help.